# Installing thermostat - No C wire or C terminal available on furnace

Tags: wiring, thermostat

So I've looked through many posts all over reddit and other websites but it seems every furnace is slightly different.

I am an early twenties guy who doesn't want to burn down his apartment.

If anyone can help me wire up my new thermostat I would appreciate it.

I attached an album showing all the diagrams on the furnace/ac which I believe is gas furnace and electric air??

People talk about switching G for C but I don't have a C connection on the furnace?

Overall this has been a very frustrating experience so I thought it best to just ask people with experience wiring them.

[image]

Comment: Where does the cable connected to Rc and Y go?  Something's amiss here, because a normal gas furnace needs to know when the air conditioner's on in order to run the fan properly...

Comment: Would be a good idea to mention the make and model of the thermostat and furnace

Comment: Don't switch G for C that makes no sense, Your fan on uses the Green wire whether that's to your furnace or AC unit it don't matter, R takes in a red wire from your furnace and sends it out on W which is a white wire going out, RC takes is a red wire from the AC unit and sends it out on Y if you don't have a transformer in your AC unit then jump R to RC, then C is your common wire that's black, it's for LCD smart thermostats that don't require batteries, C just comes from the low voltage side on the transformer to provide direct power

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow `24V VAC TRAN` there are two thick wires `SEC 1` `SEC 2` that lead to the `R` (first from the bottom)  and `COM 24V` = `C` (4th from the bottom) connections.

Answer (score 0):

You would hook up the common terminal on the thermostat to COM/24V on your circuit board